# Does JFrog's Artifactory support client side download resume?

Tags: artifactory

For example, in our case, if a client downloads partially a RPM from Artifactory and then the connection is reset, does the server support subsequent client request for download for the rest of the RPM bits?

Comment: Not sure about this one, I think that Artifactory has the ability to use split, as the JFrog CLI is using it, however, I do not believe that this can be used for resuming a download from a specific location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artifactory supports HTTP 1.1 [range requests](http://svn.tools.ietf.org/svn/wg/httpbis/specs/rfc7233.html#range.requests) since version [3.7.0](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF3X/Artifactory+3.7).